# How to disable USB device Using LDAP Server

Tags: openldap

I have LDAP server and my clients are authenticated via our LDAP server.
Due to some circumstances i would like to restrict my users from using USB MAS storage devices.

I have tried at client end tricks and it worked but i have huge number of users so i would like to block USB from my LDAP server to reduce administrative effort.

Please let me know if anyone has any way.

I am also doing research i will share if i found something.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
-Mansur

Comment: No matter what you do, you still need SOMETHING on the clients to achieve this. Better find a distributed systems management tool to distribute your client configuration.

Comment: Like in Active Directory we create a GPO for user end policy.
is there any way by we can do this ?

Comment: Not with normal/simple LDAP deployment. Windows has that part embedded in the AD client as well.